# Storing App Information

Tags: android, storage

I have been looking at different ways to hold onto some predefined character data, however I am having a hard time nailing down which would be the best solution.

An example of data would be 10 strings, 5 int arrays (of size 10 each). There would be 10+ set's of this data. The application would load in the information and inflate generic "character" objects.

Possible solutions:

XML: Due to Android's structured XML requirements it can be hard to use without making a different XML file for every character, and even then it would have ID overlapping for similar named data values.

SQLite: Wouldn't be a huge database, but databases are ugly version controlled unless it is done with a create-database script which has its own downsides (such as making sure DB is up to date between builds).

Hard-coded Objects: By far my least favorite solution, using polymorphism to hardcode all of the objects. Too dirty, not nearly as dynamic as it should be.

I would like to consider things such as version controlling the files, ease of updating (due to them only being inflated, never changed by the app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this data is baked i would suggest to use harcoded data.
Reasons.

1. In those three solution you save the data in the application.
2. If you use XML-data, you have to consume the time while code parsing inside the code. And you have to write the code that parses your xml.
3. If you use SQLite, your data will be doubled because of you have to store this database in `raw` or `assest` directory, copied in the `/data/data` folder. Futhermore, if you use Strings and SQLite by default the data will be doubled again (due to UTF-16 encoding).

If think, if only you manage the data this is more usefull to store directly inside the code. Obviously, if you do not use tons of content:)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) framework, which is comparatively faster than `SQLite` and easy to implement inside in your current code.

It handles large data too and it feels like you're using only native android classes.